# AVR studio Nibobee Library

Tags: c, avr, robotics

please I want to know what is the unit we use in AVR studio when we give the motor speed for a Nibobee Robot like :

```
motpwm_setLeft(1500);
```

what is the 1500 unit??

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://doku.nibo-roboter.de/nibobeelib/motpwm_8h.html#a3659b287b1518e21978dc6b126019682), the value is simply the raw PWM value for the device to output.

So, it's basically what percentage of the "full power" to send to the motor. What the motor then "does" with this, in terms of achieved torque and/or RPM, of course depends on the motor itself, the power electronics driving it, the available max energy, the load, and lots of other things.

Basically, it's a dimension-less value, it has no unit.

Also, it should be in the range -1024 to 1024 (which is weird, but that's what it says).

Comment: we need to make the robot move in a particular speed in cm per seconds, like the main idea is we want the robot to move in lets say a circle by giving the area to the nibobee and then It will generate the circumference of circle and depending on that the right wheel will have different speed than the other, so it can make a full circle.

Comment: and we are using the distance = speed * time formula 
distance = the circumference , time = 60 secs 
when we get the speed we are stuck in how to translate it to the motor power !!